# dummy interface on linux

Tags: linux, network-interface, interface, modprobe

I need to create a second separate virtual interface on Linux.

I choose `dummy`. And do these steps:

```
$ cat /etc/modules-load.d/dummy.conf
# Load dummy.ko at boot
```

dummy

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethdummy1
NAME=ethdummy1
DEVICE=ethdummy1
MACADDR=00:22:22:ff:ff:ff
IPADDR=10.10.10.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Seems like everything works. But on the net I see that people do these lines also:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/dummy.conf 
install dummy /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install dummy; /sbin/ip link set name ethdummy1 dev dummy0
```

What's the point of this line ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The persons who wrote this `dummy.conf` file did so to work around a limitation of the *network-scripts* configuration found for example in CentOS 7: there's no way to run an arbitrary command to help create a virtual interface (like it's possible in the Debian-mostly-used [*interfaces*](https://manpages.debian.orgifupdown/interfaces.5) file with a `pre-up` entry). If somebody gives a clue on a simple method to run such a script (ie: not having to create a full new *ifup-dummy* script) I'll be happy to edit my answer.

The *dummy* module, has a default option `numdummies=1` (the option can be found with `modinfo -p dummy`). That means when the *dummy* module is loaded for the first time, it will also auto-create (on the initial network namespace) a dummy interface. The default naming is `dummy`+first available integer, so *dummy0*.

What the *modprobe* setting does is to ensure that when the *dummy* module is loaded (as OP told, it's loaded at boot) , this implicit *dummy0* interface will be immediately renamed *ethdummy1*, and `--ignore-install` is there to prevent an infinite loop because it would just keep replacing loading of the *dummy* module by... loading of the *dummy* module.

This allows the *ifcfg-ethdummy1* configuration to work correctly: the expected interface is found as if it was an usual ethernet interface.

It's possible to continue this way (despite very awkward), by editing the `dummy.conf` file like this (I put the link parameters in the natural order by the way):

```
install dummy /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install dummy numdummies=2; /sbin/ip link set dev dummy0 name ethdummy1; /sbin/ip link set dev dummy1 name ethdummy2
```

Adding the module option `numdummies=2` created two *dummy* interface *dummy0* and *dummy1*, and they were "immediately" renamed to their final names *ethdummy1* and *ethdummy2*. Now you can add a corresponding configuration file *ifcfg-ethdummy2*.

If you just added a new configuration and don't want to reboot or lose interfaces, you can add the interface manually so the *ifup* command will still succeed after:

```
ip link add ethdummy2 type dummy
```

Why do I find the work-around in *dummy.conf* awkward? Because this won't work for the same system (eg CentOS 7) running in a container: the interfaces are always added to the initial network namespace, so the container will never see them (and also usually a container is prevented to explicitly load a module, even if a container can still indirectly trigger the loading, for example by using `ip link add type dummy`).

Personally i'd rather use for `dummy.conf` this: `options numdummies=0`: create no interface by default, and deal with it as needed. At least the result would be consistant when using or not a container.

I didn't either find that NetworkManager supports natively dummy interfaces, but at least it's scriptable. You can check the solutions offered in this link: [Dummy interface on RHEL](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/appendix/dummy-interface-on-rhel.html#dummy-interface-on-rhel). They add a script for NetworkManager, or use systemd's instantiation of a service to create an interface by starting it with the chosen name.

If you're later using a Debian-like distribution, then this is easily solved by using `pre-up ip link add ethdummy2 type dummy 2>/dev/null || :` in the *interfaces*' stanza.

Comment: I realize now you don't have the issue. But it appears CentOS7 does. What's your exact distribution?